# AddEventHandler when event handler argument is object in method

Tags: c#, events, dynamic

I have a Windows Phone page (MainPage), and in the codebehind, I want to dynamically add an event handler - for example to the MouseEnter event. The trick is, I want this event handler to have the event argument as an object:

```
    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, object args)
    {

    }
```

(The reason for this is that this is a simplified example)

This works:

```
this.MouseEnter += MyEventHandler;
```

But this throws an ArgumentException:

```
var handlerType = Type.GetType("System.EventHandler`1").
                  MakeGenericType(typeof(EventArgs));
this.GetType().GetEvent("Hold").AddEventHandler(
                  this, Delegate.CreateDelegate(handlerType, this, "MyEventHandler"));
```

And the message of the exception is:
"Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type." If I change the signature of the event handler, all works, but I want to keep it as "object" or "dynamic".

How can I add the event handler with the AddEventHandler call?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword is delegate covariance:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var t = new Test();

    var e = t.GetType().GetEvent("TestEvent");
    var te = Delegate.CreateDelegate(e.EventHandlerType, new EventHandler(MyMethod).Method);

    e.AddEventHandler(t, te);

    t.RaiseTest();
  }

  static void MyMethod(object sender, object args)
  {

  }
}

public class Test
{
  public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs { }

  public void RaiseTest()
  {
    var e = TestEvent;
    if (e != null)
      e(this, new MyEventArgs());
  }

  public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> TestEvent;
}
```

Comment: To make this work with a non-static MyMethod, e.g. if you move it to Test and change its "static" to "public", then change `var te = Delegate.CreateDelegate(e.EventHandlerType, new EventHandler(MyMethod).Method);` to `var te = Delegate.CreateDelegate(e.EventHandlerType, t, new EventHandler(t.MyMethod).Method);` .  Just spent a while figuring this out & wanted to share.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to resort to DynamicMethod and ILGenerator to generate a method that matches the signature of the eventhandler. Then in the DynamicMethod implementation invoke a global event handler that has your signature void MyEventHandler(object, object).

```
public MainPage()
{
   var handler = Create<MouseEventHandler>();
   this.LayoutRoot.MouseMove += handler;
}

public static void MyEventHandler(object sender, object args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("MyEventHandler({0}, {1})", sender, args);
}

private TDelegate Create<TDelegate>()
{
    // retrieve parameter types from delegate type
    var delegateType = typeof(TDelegate);
    var invoke = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    var parameterTypes = (from p in invoke.GetParameters()
                          select p.ParameterType).ToArray();

    // create dynamic event handler having TDelegate signature
    var method = new DynamicMethod("", null, parameterTypes);
    var myEventHandlerMethod = typeof(MainPage).GetMethod("MyEventHandler");

    var generator = method.GetILGenerator();
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, myEventHandlerMethod);    // invoke my event handler
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (TDelegate)(object)method.CreateDelegate(delegateType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous method wrapping it should do the trick:
this.MouseEnter += (s,e) => MyEventHandler(s,e);

Comment: Sorry, this won't work - I don't have access to the event property, that's why I have to use reflection. Also, I can only use reflection to access to the event's argument type.
The reason I have this.MouseEnter above is to illustrate what I want to achieve with reflection, since it is not possible to do otherways.